# Magento custom collection breaks pagination

Tags: magento, collections, pagination

I created a collection by adding items to a  Varien_Data_Collection collection object.

```
$collection = new Varien_Data_Collection();
  foreach($array_of_products as $productId){
    $collection->addItem(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId));
}
```

However when this object is passed on to Magento pager block as given below, it breaks the pagination in my custom page.

```
$pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'retailerfe.analysis.pager')
            ->setCollection($collection);
```

P.S I have never had problems with collections fetched from 
model collections like Mage::getModel('module/modelname')->getCollection(). It is just collections created by adding items to a Varien_Data_Collection Object.

Comment: please post the text of the error message, and tell us what version of Magento. v1.4 changed the way that pagination works.

Comment: There is no error message. It is just that pagination becomes a little weird. The pager calculates the page numbers correctly.

 It seems like it is not able to apply limits on the collection. All the items show on all the pages.

I use Magento v 1.5.0.1

Comment: Seems like this behavior occurs whenever a collection created by adding items to an empty Varien_Data_Collection object is made to paginate.

Comment: Can you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pager is calling [`setPageSize`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Data/Varien_Data_Collection.html#setPageSize) on your collection which - if you trace it - is only used by [`getLastPageNumber`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Data/Varien_Data_Collection.html#getLastPageNumber). This means the pager can show the number of pages accurately but that's it. It is [`Varien_Data_Collection_Db`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Data/Varien_Data_Collection_Db.html) that actually does anything with the current page number and size by rendering them as a `LIMIT` clause for SQL.

To create a collection that respects the page criteria you will have to create a descendant to the class. For ideas look at [the source of `Varien_Data_Collection_Filesystem`](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7-trunk/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Filesystem.php) and how it implements `loadData`.

---

I've just re-read your question and realised you can do this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addIdFilter($array_of_products);
```

This collection will page quite happily.

Comment: Thanks, clockworkgeek. Your explanation is correct. If I can get a good solution out of this, I will post it here.

Comment: I had to create a custom Collection and merge into it two Magento Collections ... Actually the above suggestion worked fine: it fix pagination.

I just implement a collection extending Varien_Data_Colletion and implement the loadData in a similar way described in the Varien_Data_Collection_Filesystem.

Comment: Can anyone please post the code on how to implement "Varien_Data_Collection_Filesystem" loadData method in our custom Varien_Data_Collection? I am trying to solve this pagination issue for hours without success :( @Francesco

Comment: sorry right now It passed a lot of time and don't remember. just look at the Varien_Data_Collection_Filesystem and its loadData() method.

Comment: My suggestion was to look at `loadData()` for inspiration only, not to literally implement it nor recreate it exactly.  Look at how it calculates `$from`, `$to` and `$isPaginated` and then checks them before calling `$this->addItem()`.  The secret is to only call `addItem()` for the items you know are in the current page.  If you have a more specific problem with this then try starting a new question.

Answer (score 2):

I just doubt on(may be i am wrong):

```
$collection->addItem(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId));
```

which should be like this:

```
$collection->addItem(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId)->getData());
```

Let me know if that works for you.
Thanks

**EDIT:**
Finally i figured it out.
Here is how you should do it:

```
<?php
$collection = new Varien_Data_Collection();
foreach($array_of_products as $productId){
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId); 
    $_rowObject = new Varien_Object();
    $_rowObject->setData($product->getData());
    $collection->addItem($_rowObject);
}
```

Comment: [`addItem`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Data/Varien_Data_Collection.html#addItem) requires a `Varien_Object`, not an array.

Comment: Agree with @clockworkgeek. I tried it anyway. Gave me an error. Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /var/www/magento/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php on line 390 . Thanks for the responses.

Comment: This has not helped me with the pagination. As @clockworkgeek said, Varien_Data_Collection as such does not help pagination. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is provided.

```
class Test_Featuredsalons_Block_Featuredsalons extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('featuredsalons/featuredsalons')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'custom.pager');
        $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getCollection()->load();

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }

    public function getCollection()     
     {            
        $limit      =   10;
        $curr_page  =   1;

        if(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('p'))
        {
            $curr_page  =   Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('p');
        }
        //Calculate Offset  
        $offset     =   ($curr_page - 1) * $limit;

        $collection =   Mage::getModel('featuredsalons/featuredsalons')->getCollection()
                                                    ->addFieldToFilter('status',1);     
        $collection->getSelect()->limit($limit,$offset);

        return $collection;
    }   
}
```

Thanks,
Kashif

Answer (score 0):

Use the following class to extend the Varien Data Collection class:

```
class Pageable_Varien_Data_Collection extends Varien_Data_Collection
{
    /**
     * Load data
     *
     * @param   bool $printQuery
     * @param   bool $logQuery
     *
     * @return  Pageable_Varien_Data_Collection
     */
    public function load($printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
    {
        if ($this->isLoaded()) {
            return $this;
        }
        $this->_renderLimit();
        $this->_setIsLoaded();
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return  Pageable_Varien_Data_Collection
     */
    protected function _renderLimit()
    {
        if ($this->_pageSize) {
            $currentPage = $this->getCurPage();
            $pageSize = $this->_pageSize;
            $firstItem = (($currentPage - 1) * $pageSize + 1);
            $lastItem = $firstItem + $pageSize;
            $iterator = 1;
            foreach ($this->getItems() as $key => $item) {
                $pos = $iterator;
                $iterator++;
                if ($pos >= $firstItem && $pos <= $lastItem) {
                    continue;
                }
                $this->removeItemByKey($key);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve collection all items count
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getSize()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_totalRecords)) {
            $this->_totalRecords = count($this->getItems());
        }
        return intval($this->_totalRecords);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve collection items
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->_items;
    }
}
```